# mobileapp - web communication ,application connection to web using her own UI concept?

Tags: android, mobile-phones, mobile-website

I want to work with a site how do I do it
let's say I want my app to grab some information from a site.

lets say I have a site which store all the phone numbers data and I want an application app who will have a menu where you just need to click name and address and the app find for you using the web(a web which supply this service ) the person phone number .

i want the user to see my UI(the application UI) and the app to communicate to this site and by asking the right queries getting the information.

is there any open source example of that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so you'd want something similar to this:

http://developer.whitepages.com/docs/Methods/find_person

You can just get your app to call that and do whatever you want with the data it returns.

Obviously this is just an example of an API you could use to get what you need.